# Detach a Spring Rest processing

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-integration

In a Spring Boot App with Rest entrypoints, I need to return immediatly http status to the caller.

But considering my rest entrypoints processing are time consuming tasks, I need to detach the processing itself to allow immediate response.

I'm considering two solutions :

- Simply by using @Async annotation
- Using Spring Integration with a dedicaced flow for each task

"Converting" my process to Spring Integration would be a little tricky, so, does this solution should be considered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if your downstream logic is pretty simple and one-step service invoker, there might be really no reason to move to Spring Integration.

OTOH with the `@MessagingGateway` on board your `@Controller` would be almost the same as with `@Async`. Only the difference that you get the full benefit of integration with Spring Integration.